# Can Borg drones control their ships with their minds?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, technology, borg, telepathy

I've seen some people get upset at seeing Borg drones press buttons on computer consoles, arguing that they should be able to simply control the ship via their hive mind connection.

I'm pretty sure we've seen the Borg Queen appear to control the ship with just her mind, but I always figured she used the hive mind to communicate her orders to Borg drones off-screen who then pressed the needed buttons to execute her commands.

If I'm wrong, can all Borg drones control the ship, or is it just the Queen?

Answer (score 1):

The components of any borg ship may or may not be connected directly to the control of the hive mind at any given time. They are assimilated from other vessels which may not be immediately compatible, and battle damage or maintenance could disconnect sections.

This isn't a problem though as the borg still control them through the hivemind, just using one or more drones as a relay as the most efficient path available. Any direct connection can just be considered a redundant backup in fact.

EDIT: As per the request for an example. The most recently seen would be from Picard S01E08 where

> Seven of Nine plugs in and controls the start up of a Borg cube

Comment: Do you have any proof of your statement? E.g. episodes where they've controlled the ship via the hive mind directly

Comment: Example of an episode showing this added

Comment: Which brings up the question of whether a wired connection is needed.  Wi-fi was [just becoming a thing IRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11_(legacy_mode)) during ST:V's run.

Comment: You say Seven of nine "Plugs in" to the Borg cube, does this mean she physically plugs in? I can't remember myself.

Comment: She twiddles the holographic interface and some snakey cables come down and push against her spine which has started glowing for some reason.